# Using double type with useState and assigning based on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have 2 classes, one extending other:

```
export class DoIt implements IDoIt { //some fields }
```

and

```
export class DoThat extends DoIt implements IDoThat { // one extra field }
```

Now, I can receive one of 2 responses, and based on it I would like to use the appropriate type.

What I tried:

```
const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState<DoIt | DoThat>();
```

and then (`task` is my response here):

```
  if(task instanceof DoThat)
          setCurrentTask(task as DoThat);
  else
          setCurrentTask(task as DoIt);
```

But `currentTask` is always of type `DoIt`, even if the extra field is present. Am I doing this correctly or missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentTask` can be either `DoIt` or `DoThat`.  You don't know which one it is.  `DoThat` extends `DoIt`, so you know that you always have *at least* `DoIt` and can access all of the `DoIt` fields safely without knowing the type.

If you want to use the `DoThat` property then you have to check that `currentTask` is `DoThat` when you *access* it, not when you *set* it.

It is fine to call `setCurrentTask` with either one, so your `if(task instanceof DoThat)` is unnecessary.

```
export class DoIt {
  constructor(public it: string) {}
}

export class DoThat extends DoIt {
  constructor(it: string, public that: string) {
    super(it);
  }
}

export const Component = () => {
  const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState<DoIt | DoThat>();

  const setTask = (task: DoIt) => {
    setCurrentTask(task);
  };

  // this is fine, because every DoThat is also a DoIt
  setTask(new DoThat("a", "b"));

  // can access currentTask.that conditionally
  const that = currentTask instanceof DoThat ? currentTask.that : "default value";
};
```